Problem with connecting to Firestore and Firestore emulator
I am encountering strange errors while attempting to connect to Firestore, whether using the emulator or not. The rules set for testing are as follows (both locally and online):
rules_version = "2";
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
     
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}

Here is the code for listening/writing:
func subscribe() {
      if listenerRegistration == nil {
        listenerRegistration = db.collection("units").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
          guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No documents")
            return
          }

          let units = documents.compactMap { queryDocumentSnapshot in
            try? queryDocumentSnapshot.data(as: UnitModel.self)
          }
        }
      }
    }

    private func addUnit(_ unit: UnitModel) {
        do {
          let _ = try db.collection("units").addDocument(from: unit)
        }
        catch let error {
            print("Firebase error \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
      }

So no matter what I try, I am getting errors in console (by the way, catch block never executes):

10.22.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: An
internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for
more information.  This typically indicates that your device does not
have a healthy Internet connection at the moment. The client will
operate in offline mode until it is able to successfully connect to

or

10.22.1 - [FirebaseFirestore][I-FST000001] WatchStream (104e08808) Stream error: 'Unknown: An internal error has occurred, print and
inspect the error details for more information.'

Also Firebase Authentication works on both simulator and in live environment. Which makes those errors about internet connection questionable.
For example for Auth, I use this for simulator:
 enum Development {
        static let kFirebaseAuthEmulatorPort = 9099
        static let kFirebaseFirestoreEmulatorPort = 8080
        static let kMachineLocalIP = "192.168.0.10"
    }


Auth.auth().useEmulator(withHost: Constants.Development.kMachineLocalIP,
                                port: Constants.Development.kFirebaseAuthEmulatorPort)

and it works. For Firestore, I use Firestore.firestore().useEmulator(...) and simply use different constants, but without luck. Also Firebase realtime database works for me. Just Firestore doesn't.
Does anybody know what the reason might be for this not working? I hope I am making a mistake in how I am trying to write/listen for changes from Firestore...?

Actually it worked. I read somewhere to do explicit Auth.auth().signOut(). Not sure why this happened though, but for me this was a fix. Will see if it happen again :)
